# sas using % wildcard with substr

Tags: sas

I'm trying to subset some data with the following code:

```
data want;
set have;
array fx(12) fx1-fx12;
    do i=1 to 12;
    if substr(dx(i),1,4) in ('1115')
       or substr(fx(i),1,5) in ('1146%')
    then output;
end;
run;
```

I cross reference the data output using proc freq to the original dataset. The frequency counts for '1115' matches as they should. They don't for '1146%'. I thought '%' is a wildcard that I can use?

I also tried `'/^1146\d*/'`

Answer (score 2):

The `%` wildcard is recognized by the `WHERE` `LIKE` operator.  For the `IF` statement you will want to use the string prefix equality (i.e. starts with) operator `=:` or the prefix in set operator `IN:`

Also, since you are just `substr` 5 characters, you could `substr` 4 characters and check `= '1146'`.  Furthermore, since you are `substr` from position 1 (1st character) you won't need to do `substr` at all (see 3rd example) when using `IN:`.

In order to use Perl regular expression pattern matching use the `PRXMATCH` function.  Your pattern `'/^1146\d*/'` does not need `\d*` (0 or more digits). 
`'/^1146/'` will match anything that `'/^1146\d*/'` does.

Example(s):

```
    if substr(dx(i),1,4) in ('1115') or fx(i) =: '1146' then output;
```

```
    if substr(dx(i),1,4) in ('1115') or substr(fx(i),1,4) = '1146' then output;
```

```
    /* expanded example for case of checking two prefix possibilities */
    if dx(i) in: ('1115') or fx(i) in: ('1146', '124') then output;
```

```
    if dx(i) =: '1115' or prxmatch('/^1146/', fx(i)) then output;
```